# How can I make it so that my variable is used throughout the whole method

Tags: java, arrays

If I have an int in my for loop, how can I print it out after my for loop. It gets an error saying i is not a variable?

```
for (int i = 1; i < ar.length; i++) {
}   
System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: Don't put visibility modifiers in local variable declarations. Remove that `public` keyword in the declaration of `i`.

Comment: Remove public modifier and insert println method into curly brackets of for loop

Comment: One tip (not related to your question, but that's important): you should follow the language conventions for naming your variables, methods and classes. The proper name of this method should be secondTiny. See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't make local variables (variables declared inside methods) `public`; that's only for member variables (variables at class level, declared outside a method).

You have to understand **scope**. Variables are only visible within a scope. The scope of a local variable is from the point it is defined until the closing `}` of the block it is defined in. For variables declared in a `for`, the scope is the body of the `for` statement (the `{ ... }` after the `for`).

So, the variable `i` is does not exist beyond the body of the `for` statement.

You have to declare `i` outside the `for`:

```
int i;

for (i = 1; i < ar.length; i++) {
    // ...
}

System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: So as long as it is in the scope of the main class, the variable i will apply to the full code, correct?

Comment: @Rich if the variable is declared inside a class, outside a method, then it is a [member variable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/variables.html) and it will be visible in all non-static methods of the class.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 1; i < ar.length; i++) {
}
```

When you declare the variable inside the loop (without `public`, mind you), it is only available inside of the loop. If you want to refer to it outside of the loop, move the declaration out of the loop.

```
int i;

for (i = 1; i < ar.length; i++) {
}

System.out.println(i);
```

Note that this will only print one line. It'll print the final value of `i` after the loop finishes.

If your intention was to print all the values of `i` while the loop iterates, instead you should move the print call inside the loop. In that case you could leave `i` as a loop variable.

```
for (int i = 1; i < ar.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
}
```